# "be cool with something"

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language, slang

I'd like to know if it would be completely natural to use "cool with" here?

Young man: You mind if I play some rap music?

Older man: Not at all.

As the music comes on, the older man starts bobbing his head slightly to the beat **to show that he's cool with the rap genre.** (he wants to show that he has nothing against rap music, maybe even likes it.)

According to dictionaries the definitions of "be cool with something" are "to be happy to accept a situation or suggestion" and "to not find the thing objectionable."

Is the latter fitting for my example?

Answer (score 1):

You are 100 percent correct about the meaning.

However, "cool" is very informal, and "genre" is not, so it seems out of place. I would just remove "genre" altogether.

Also, while the old man might call it "rap music," the young man would probably call it "hip-hop" music. So the narrator appears to be an old man as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your meaning is correct. That's how to apply "be cool with something".

However, to analyze further:

1. It may be over-explaining. Is it necessary? Consider the following passage, and whether it doesn't already convey the idea sufficiently.

> Young man: You mind if I play some rap music?
> Older man: Not at all.
> As the music comes on, the older man starts bobbing his head slightly to the beat.
> A moment later, the phone rings loudly.

2. Secondly, "to be cool with something" is sort of colloquial. Should the omniscient narrator be using such a conversational style?  It sounds like something one of the characters themselves would say. "Hey, he's cool with rap?", the young man thought.

Comment: "sort of colloquial"? - I'd say it's ***extremely*** colloquial / slangy!